Python script jobs fail with permission denied error in Apache Dolphin Standalone Server
I'm trying to create a cronjob with a python script in apache dolphin scheduler.
These are the steps I followed. (Used the default admin user and default tenant)

Created a project
Created a workflow
Added a python node. (In the script section added a line print('Hello From Python!')). Saved the node and workflow.
Scheduled it to run in every minute and made the workflow and scheduler online.

When I checked the logs, I noticed there's a permission denied error and after the execution of the workflow it is deleting the script files created for the execution.
Then, for further investigation I enable develop mode.
(made development.state=true in standalone-server/conf/common.properties).
OS version: fedora 40
Apache dolphin version: 3.2.1
Following is the logs of the workflow execution.
[LOG-PATH]: /home/ishad/Software/apache-dolphinscheduler-3.2.1-bin/standalone-server/logs/20240723/14374012970432/1/1/1.log, [HOST]:  192.168.49.1:1234

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.763 +0530 - ***********************************************************************************************

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.771 +0530 - *********************************  Initialize task context  ***********************************

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.771 +0530 - ***********************************************************************************************

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.771 +0530 - Begin to initialize task

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.772 +0530 - Set task startTime: 1721727420772

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.772 +0530 - Set task appId: 1_1

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.779 +0530 - End initialize task {

  "taskInstanceId" : 1,

  "taskName" : "n1",

  "firstSubmitTime" : 1721727420494,

  "startTime" : 1721727420772,

  "taskType" : "PYTHON",

  "workflowInstanceHost" : "192.168.49.1:5678",

  "host" : "192.168.49.1:1234",

  "logPath" : "/home/ishad/Software/apache-dolphinscheduler-3.2.1-bin/standalone-server/logs/20240723/14374012970432/1/1/1.log",

  "processId" : 0,

  "processDefineCode" : 14374012970432,

  "processDefineVersion" : 1,

  "processInstanceId" : 1,

  "scheduleTime" : 1721727420000,

  "executorId" : 1,

  "cmdTypeIfComplement" : 6,

  "tenantCode" : "default",

  "processDefineId" : 0,

  "projectId" : 0,

  "projectCode" : 14374006444992,

  "taskParams" : "{\"localParams\":[],\"rawScript\":\"print(\\\"Hello from python!\\\")\",\"resourceList\":[]}",

  "prepareParamsMap" : {

    "system.task.definition.name" : {

      "prop" : "system.task.definition.name",

      "direct" : "IN",

      "type" : "VARCHAR",

      "value" : "n1"

    },

    "system.project.name" : {

      "prop" : "system.project.name",

      "direct" : "IN",

      "type" : "VARCHAR",

      "value" : null

    },

    "system.project.code" : {

      "prop" : "system.project.code",

      "direct" : "IN",

      "type" : "VARCHAR",

      "value" : "14374006444992"

    },

    "system.workflow.instance.id" : {

      "prop" : "system.workflow.instance.id",

      "direct" : "IN",

      "type" : "VARCHAR",

      "value" : "1"

    },

    "system.biz.curdate" : {

      "prop" : "system.biz.curdate",

      "direct" : "IN",

      "type" : "VARCHAR",

      "value" : "20240723"

    },

    "system.biz.date" : {

      "prop" : "system.biz.date",

      "direct" : "IN",

      "type" : "VARCHAR",

      "value" : "20240722"

    },

    "system.task.instance.id" : {

      "prop" : "system.task.instance.id",

      "direct" : "IN",

      "type" : "VARCHAR",

      "value" : "1"

    },

    "system.workflow.definition.name" : {

      "prop" : "system.workflow.definition.name",

      "direct" : "IN",

      "type" : "VARCHAR",

      "value" : "w1"

    },

    "system.task.definition.code" : {

      "prop" : "system.task.definition.code",

      "direct" : "IN",

      "type" : "VARCHAR",

      "value" : "14374008341824"

    },

    "system.workflow.definition.code" : {

      "prop" : "system.workflow.definition.code",

      "direct" : "IN",

      "type" : "VARCHAR",

      "value" : "14374012970432"

    },

    "system.datetime" : {

      "prop" : "system.datetime",

      "direct" : null,

      "type" : null,

      "value" : "20240723150700"

    }

  },

  "taskAppId" : "1_1",

  "taskTimeout" : 2147483647,

  "workerGroup" : "default",

  "delayTime" : 0,

  "currentExecutionStatus" : "SUBMITTED_SUCCESS",

  "endTime" : 0,

  "dryRun" : 0,

  "paramsMap" : {

    "system.datetime" : {

      "prop" : "system.datetime",

      "direct" : null,

      "type" : null,

      "value" : "20240723150700"

    }

  },

  "cpuQuota" : -1,

  "memoryMax" : -1,

  "testFlag" : 0,

  "logBufferEnable" : false,

  "dispatchFailTimes" : 0

}

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.781 +0530 - ***********************************************************************************************

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.781 +0530 - *********************************  Load task instance plugin  *********************************

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.781 +0530 - ***********************************************************************************************

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.839 +0530 - Send task status RUNNING_EXECUTION master: 192.168.49.1:1234

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.842 +0530 - Current tenant is default tenant, will use bootstrap user: ishad to execute the task

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.842 +0530 - TenantCode: ishad check successfully

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.856 +0530 - WorkflowInstanceExecDir: /tmp/dolphinscheduler/exec/process/ishad/14374006444992/14374012970432_1/1/1 check successfully

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.857 +0530 - Create TaskChannel: org.apache.dolphinscheduler.plugin.task.python.PythonTaskChannel successfully

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.858 +0530 - Download resources successfully: 

ResourceContext(resourceItemMap={})

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.861 +0530 - Download upstream files: [] successfully

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.864 +0530 - Task plugin instance: PYTHON create successfully

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.867 +0530 - Initialize python task params {

  "localParams" : [ ],

  "varPool" : null,

  "rawScript" : "print(\"Hello from python!\")",

  "resourceList" : [ ]

}

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.868 +0530 - Success initialized task plugin instance successfully

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.868 +0530 - Set taskVarPool: null successfully

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.870 +0530 - ***********************************************************************************************

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.870 +0530 - *********************************  Execute task instance  *************************************

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.870 +0530 - ***********************************************************************************************

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.870 +0530 - raw python script : print("Hello from python!")

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.874 +0530 - tenantCode :ishad, task dir:/tmp/dolphinscheduler/exec/process/ishad/14374006444992/14374012970432_1/1/1

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.874 +0530 - generate python script file:/tmp/dolphinscheduler/exec/process/ishad/14374006444992/14374012970432_1/1/1/py_1_1.py

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.874 +0530 - #-*- encoding=utf8 -*-


print("Hello from python!")

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.903 +0530 - Final Shell file is: 

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.904 +0530 - ****************************** Script Content *****************************************************************

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.904 +0530 - #!/bin/bash

BASEDIR=$(cd `dirname $0`; pwd)

cd $BASEDIR

${PYTHON_LAUNCHER} /tmp/dolphinscheduler/exec/process/ishad/14374006444992/14374012970432_1/1/1/py_1_1.py

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.904 +0530 - ****************************** Script Content *****************************************************************

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.906 +0530 - Executing shell command : sudo -u ishad -i /tmp/dolphinscheduler/exec/process/ishad/14374006444992/14374012970432_1/1/1/1_1.sh

[ERROR] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.920 +0530 - Get task pid failed

java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final int java.lang.ProcessImpl.pid accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @679d4c1c

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:391)

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:367)

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:315)

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:183)

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:177)

    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.plugin.task.api.AbstractCommandExecutor.getProcessId(AbstractCommandExecutor.java:339)

    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.plugin.task.api.AbstractCommandExecutor.run(AbstractCommandExecutor.java:146)

    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.plugin.task.python.PythonTask.handle(PythonTask.java:96)

    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.worker.runner.DefaultWorkerTaskExecutor.executeTask(DefaultWorkerTaskExecutor.java:54)

    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.worker.runner.WorkerTaskExecutor.run(WorkerTaskExecutor.java:175)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)

    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:00.922 +0530 - process start, process id is: 0

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:01.916 +0530 -  -> 

    /tmp/dolphinscheduler/exec/process/ishad/14374006444992/14374012970432_1/1/1/1_1.sh: line 4: /tmp/dolphinscheduler/exec/process/ishad/14374006444992/14374012970432_1/1/1/py_1_1.py: Permission denied

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:01.918 +0530 - process has exited. execute path:/tmp/dolphinscheduler/exec/process/ishad/14374006444992/14374012970432_1/1/1, processId:0 ,exitStatusCode:126 ,processWaitForStatus:true ,processExitValue:126

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:01.919 +0530 - ***********************************************************************************************

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:01.920 +0530 - *********************************  Finalize task instance  ************************************

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:01.920 +0530 - ***********************************************************************************************

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:01.923 +0530 - Upload output files: [] successfully

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:01.936 +0530 - Send task execute status: FAILURE to master : 192.168.49.1:1234

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:01.937 +0530 - Remove the current task execute context from worker cache

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:01.937 +0530 - The current execute mode is develop mode, will not clear the task execute file: /tmp/dolphinscheduler/exec/process/ishad/14374006444992/14374012970432_1/1/1

[INFO] 2024-07-23 15:07:01.939 +0530 - FINALIZE_SESSION

The files created for execution in /tmp/dolphinscheduler/exec/process/ishad/14374006444992/14374012970432_1/1/1 is as below.
drwxr-xr-x 2 ishad ishad  80 Jul 23 15:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 ishad ishad  60 Jul 23 15:07 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ishad ishad 161 Jul 23 15:07 1_1.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 ishad ishad  51 Jul 23 15:07 py_1_1.py

It's obvious that the permission denied error is due to the missing execution permission for the py_1_1.py file created.
Even though I manually set the execution permissions for the file the next workflow execution instance is creating another set of scripts.
How can I get this fixed?.

If you have installed it within docker container, then we will have to install python inside the docker container.
Follow the steps and work will be done:
log in inside the shell of container:
sudo docker exec -it dolphinscheduler /bin/bash

sudo apt install python

find out the python installation library
mostly usr/bin/python*version

4.create a environment in dolphinscheduler named PythonEnv
and give config
export PYTHON_LAUNCHER='usr/bin/python*version'
and give this env to python program and python program will start running on docker standalone dolphin scheduler environment

It is not problem of file permission of the python script file (py_1_1.py file
in your case). It is the problem of the environment variable PYTHON_LAUNCHER, if it is not set, the script
${PYTHON_LAUNCHER} /tmp/dolphinscheduler/exec/process/ishad/14374006444992/14374012970432_1/1/1/py_1_1.py

will be call the python file directly, but the intended one should be:
python /tmp/dolphinscheduler/exec/process/ishad/14374006444992/14374012970432_1/1/1/py_1_1.py

Then, you will certainly get the permmision error.
